# Create a View with all values from pivot table in one field in a MySQL

Tags: mysql, view, pivot-table

I have a really big model with many "many to many" relations.
I create a View using many tables for better search results, but still can't load in one field all values in a pivot table.

What I have:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW westates AS
        SELECT
            concat(estates.locale,estates.id) as code,
            cities.name as city,
            councils.name as council,
            states.name as state,
            countries.name as country,
            concat(cities.name,' (',councils.name,')') as city_council,
            estates.*

        FROM estates
            JOIN countries  ON (estates.country_id = countries.id)
            JOIN states     ON (estates.state_id = states.id)
            JOIN councils   ON (estates.city_council_id = councils.id)
            JOIN cities     ON (estates.city_id = cities.id)
```

What I want (in pseudocode)

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW westates AS
        SELECT
            concat(estates.locale,estates.id) as code,
            cities.name as city,
            councils.name as council,
            states.name as state,
            countries.name as country,
            concat(cities.name,' (',councils.name,')') as city_council,
            estates.*
            (SELECT all istallations from installations) as installations //and get all values from pivot table

        FROM estates
            JOIN countries  ON (estates.country_id = countries.id)
            JOIN states     ON (estates.state_id = states.id)
            JOIN councils   ON (estates.city_council_id = councils.id)
            JOIN cities     ON (estates.city_id = cities.id)
            JOIN estates_intallations ON (estates.id = estates_installations.estate_id) // this is the pivot table
```

And get in "installations" field all ids in any format:

instatallations content could be:

instatallations => "1 4 7 15" or "[1,4,7,15]" , etc.

I can do it with PHP but I need to use one query avoid using thousands of queries for creating this View.

(Asked recently but maybe making it incomprensible)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the subquery with

```
( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(inst_num)
      FROM installations AS i
      WHERE i... = ... ) AS installations
```

For `inst_num` use whatever column gives you 1,4, etc.
For `i...=...` use whatever condition ties `installations to the other table(s).

(And you are missing a comma.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rick James. For anybody with the same problem (little experience with SQL) I want to complete the answer.
Imagine we have to tables, main table of Estates and a pivot table with some Extras named estates_extras.

```
table estates
columns id, address

table estates_extras
columns estate_id, extra_id
```

We want a view that have:

```
table westates
columns estates.id, estates.address, extras
like
    id       address         extras
    25000    My nice road    1,5,8
```

First of all:
If we do not include DISTINCT we will have in our view the same number of columns repeated, as elements have in extras, in this example (with three extras):

```
results
    id       address         extras
    25000    My nice road    1,5,8
    25000    My nice road    1,5,8
    25000    My nice road    1,5,8
```

And if we don't add JOIN as LEFT JOIN we have not results for Estates that does not have almost one extra. So, wiht this query we will have all our Estates and if they have extras, a comma separated list of them.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW westates AS
    SELECT  DISTINCT
        estates.id,
        estates.address,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(estates_extras.extras_id) FROM estates_extras
        WHERE estates_extras.estate_id = estates.id ) AS extras
   FROM estates
   LEFT JOIN estates_extras ON (estates_extras.estates_id = estates.id)
```